# return array in lua from a sqlite database

Tags: lua

How do you return an array from a sqlite database in lua?

I have this sameple code here:

```
function getMoveName()
    tempMoveName = {}
    for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM movetable") do
        tempMoveName = row.movename .. " " .. row.totalcubicfeet .. " " .. row.totalitem .. "\n"
    end
    return tempMoveName
end
```

which will return the content of the database and then print the content with this line of code:

```
local displaymovenames = mydatabase.getMoveName()

print ( displaymovenames )
```

however it only returns the last data and not all of the contents of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is for every row, you just store the row data **in the variable  tempMoveName** and hence overwriting the previous value.

You need to add the rowData **to the table tempMoveName**.

```
function getMoveName()
    tempMoveName = {}
    for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM movetable") do
        local rowData = row.movename .. " " .. row.totalcubicfeet.." "..row.totalitem.."\n"
        tempMoveName[#tempMoveName+1] = rowData
    end
    return tempMoveName
end
```

**EDIT**

To access the table elements you have to do the following

```
for i=1,#tempMoveName do 
   print(tempMoveName[i]) 
end
```

note that `#tempMoveName` gives the length of the table(i.e no. of elements in the table)

P.S if you are going to do a lot of coding in Lua, I'd suggest you get a grip on the basics of Tables, cos table is the main datatype of Lua.  Arrays, lists, dictionaries, classes and almost everything are implemented via tables. Here is a [tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial) for a start!

Comment: it's only printing this `table: 0x10a6516e0`

Comment: Thank you sir, ok will do that... :)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with SQL or databases; this is *basic* Lua stuff here.

This:

```
tempMoveName = {}
```

creates a table and stores the table into the (global) variable named `tempMoveName`.

This:

```
tempMoveName = row.movename .. " " .. row.totalcubicfeet .. " " .. row.totalitem .. "\n"
```

Creates a big string from concatenating other strings (don't forget about `string.format`) and stores that in the (global) variable named `tempMoveName`.

Note what I said: "stores it *in the variable*". Not "in the *table stored* in the variable".

It's no different from doing this:

```
tempMoveName = 1
tempMoveName = "foo"
```

This doesn't combine a string with an integer in some way. `tempMoveName` held `1`, then it was replaced with `"foo"`.

Tables aren't special; they're *values* just like anything else in Lua. Variables hold values. So if you change which value is stored in a variable, you have changed which value is stored there. You haven't affected the value itself, only where it is stored.

If you have a table stored in a variable, and you want to build an array, you should access the elements *within* the table, not the variable itself. This is done in the usual way:

```
tempMoveName[#tempMoveName + 1] = row.movename .. " " .. row.totalcubicfeet .. " " .. row.totalitem .. "\n"
```

Alternatively, you can use `table.insert`:

```
table.insert(tempMoveName, row.movename .. " " .. row.totalcubicfeet .. " " .. row.totalitem .. "\n")
```

Lastly, if `tempMoveName` is meant to be temporary (as the name suggests), then you should declare it as a `local` variable.

Comment: it's only printing this `table: 0x10a6516e0`